# Allow a Vf button to execute an action and onClick in a particular order?

Tags: visualforce, button

As of now, I have a vf page with a save button for a form:

```
<apex:commandButton action="{! saveFields }" value="Save"/>
```

I now want to be able to specify an `onClick` action causing the current window to close/refresh depending on the outcome of the `saveFields` action. For that, I thought of calling a js function with the `onClick` event like so:

```
<apex:commandButton action="{! saveFields }" status="busy" value="Save" onclick="saveHandler()"/>
```

Furthermore, I want to make sure the `onclick` event is handled only after the action completes.

Is this the right way to go about it?

Comment: You can use action function oncomplete attribute for this.

Comment: So, you mean change `onclick` to `oncomplete`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is the sample code how to use oncomplete attribute in actionfunction. First you need to call actionfunction. Once the actionfunction's "action" method is executed, method specified in oncomplete attribute will be called.

```
<apex:page>    
   <script>
    function callActionFUnction(){
        call();      // Action function is called using name attribute of action function.
    }
    function saveHandler(){
        // This function will be called after execution of saveFields action in controller. 
    }
   </script>
    <apex:actionfunction action="{!saveFields }" oncomplete="saveHandler()" name="call" reRender="success"/>
    <apex:commandButton status="busy" value="Save" onclick="callActionFUnction()"/>
 </apex:page>
```

Comment: You can directly call actionFunction from oncomplete, intermediate JS function is optional; would be used only if any additional manipulation is neede to be done.

Comment: true @RahulSharma

Comment: @MuzammilBajaria What if we give Both action and Onclick event in the same command Button, And when clicking the Command button executes First? Onclick or Action?